# how to call a helper method on a button click inside a view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m using a third party custom helper which opens up a report. I have wrapped it inside a another helper method in my view as below

```
@helper OpenReport(string reportName)
{
   @Html.MvcReportViewer("/FolderName/"+reportName,
   new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" })
}
```

I need to call this helper method on a button or an anchor click. How can we possibly do that?

I m trying something like this which does not seem to work

```
<a href="#" onclick="@OpenReport("ReportName");return false;" >My Report</a>
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Either render it inside a hidden element and show it on the button click, or use ajax to call a controller method that returns a partial view and update the DOM

Comment: Try making AJAX call.